# How to get an array from a database in Rails3 even when there's only one record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails3, I have the following line:

```
@messages = Message.where("recipient_deleted = ?", false).find_by_recipient_id(@user.id)
```

In my view, I loop through `@messages` and print out each message, as such:

```
<% for message in @messages %>
    <%= message.sender_id %>
    <%= message.created_at %>
    <%= message.body %>
<% end %>
```

This works flawlessly when there are several messages.

The problem is that when I have one message, I get an error thrown at me:
`undefined method`each'`

How do I force rails to always return an array of messages even if there's only one message so that `each` always works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
@messages = Message.where(recipient_deleted => false, :recipient_id => @user.id)
```

```
@messages.each do |message|
  <%= message.sender_id %>
  <%= message.created_at %>
  <%= message.body %>
end
```

I think you're problem is that you are nested things really weird. Both should be part of the where clause

Comment: thanks you. does the way you wrote `where` automatically escape for SQL injection?

Comment: moreso than yours actually :). your's wasn't actually escaping. you have to put it in an array to escape => .where(['table.column = ?', value]) [note the square brackets]. did this work for you problem? if so, could you mark it as correct?

Comment: @seth.vargo: no you don't have to put it into an array to escape.

Comment: Seth's answer is good, but you can also convert a single value to an array by wrapping Array() around it and it will handle an array parameter by leaving it as an array, i.e. Array(1) => Array([1]) => [1].